# R Term frequency from large document set

Tags: r, sorting, text-mining

I have a data frame like this

```
ID       content
 1       hello you how are you
 1       you are ok
 2       test
```

I need to get the frequency by id for each word in the content which is space separated. Which is basically finding the unique terms in the column and finding the frequency and display grouped by Id

```
ID      hello    you   how   are  ok    test
 1        1       3     1    2     1     0
 2        0       0     0    0     0     1
```

I tried

```
test<- unique(unlist(strsplit(temp$val, split=" ")))

df<- cbind(temp, sapply(test, function(y) apply(temp, 1, function(x) as.integer(y %in% unlist(strsplit(x, split=" "))))))
```

This gives the ungrouped solution which I'm trying to group now, but I have over 20000 unique values in content, is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a package made for text-mining?

```
# your data
text <- read.table(text = "
ID      content
1       'hello you how are you'
1       'you are ok'
2       'test'", header = T,  stringsAsFactors = FALSE) # remember the stringAsFactors life saver!
```

---

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
# here we put in column all the words
unnested <- text %>%
            unnest_tokens(word, content)

# a classic data.frame from a table of frequencies
as.data.frame.matrix(table(unnested$ID, unnested$word))
  are hello how ok test you
1   2     1   1  1    0   3
2   0     0   0  0    1   0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, unlist(strsplit(content, split = " ")), by = ID
           ][, dcast(.SD, ID ~ V1)]
#   ID are hello how ok test you
#1:  1   2     1   1  1    0   3
#2:  2   0     0   0  0    1   0
```

---

In the first part we use `unlist(strsplit(content, split = " "))` by groups of `ID`, which gives this output:

```
#   ID    V1
#1:  1 hello
#2:  1   you
#3:  1   how
#4:  1   are
#5:  1   you
#6:  1   you
#7:  1   are
#8:  1    ok
#9:  2  test
```

In the next step we use `dcast` to spread the data into wide format.

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L), content = c("hello you how are you", 
"you are ok", "test")), .Names = c("ID", "content"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```